# Why do array keys change when iterating through them for the same type?

Tags: typescript

```
const expected_keys: String[] = [
    "q",
    "w",
    "e",
    "r",
    "t",
    "y"
];

export function lint(data: any): object {

    var working_keys: String[] = [];
    var linted_data: any = {};

    for (let key in data) {
        console.log(key);                    // Print 1
        if (expected_keys.includes(key)) {
            working_keys.push(key);
        }
    }

    console.log(working_keys);               // Print 2

    for (let key in working_keys) {
        console.log(key);                    // Print 3
        linted_data[working_keys[key]] = data[working_keys[key]];
    }

    return linted_data;
}
```

On the first print, it looks like the following:

```
q
w
e
r
t
y
```

On the second print, it is also qwerty. However, for the third print, i get indexes 0-5 instead of qwerty. Why is this? Both of these arrays have the same type of `String[]`. Does it have something to do with `push()`?

Take data to be the following:

```
{
    "q": "info",
    "w": "info",
    "e": "info",
    "r": "info",
    "t": "info",
    "y": "info",
}
```

And how come I get the following error but the typescript still compiles and runs as expected?

```
Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type.

46             linted_data[working_keys[key]] = data[working_keys[key]];
```

Comment: With regard to the last question, the correct type in TS is `string`, not `String`. On mobile so I can't address the main question.

Comment: What exactly is `data`?  You have it typed as `any` and haven't included it so this doesn't constitute a [mcve].  But it's obvious that `data` is some object type, and *not* an array.   And `working_keys` is an array.  The keys of an array are numeric.  So you're iterating the keys of different things and they are different; not sure why you expect them to be the same.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for...in` syntax loops through the properties of an object.

Your third time through is iterating over an array's properties, which are actually the indices of the items in the array.

If you want the value of `key` to be an item of the array, you should use `for...of` syntax, or `working_keys.forEach` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score 3):

First of all: if you access the Array iterator like `working_keys` the better approach would be to use `for .. of` loop

Second thing: Try to define the object property with `defineProperty` constructor like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(linted_data, key, { value: data });
```

At last: There might be a problem with typescript type setting under the hood I suppose so you are using String object as a key instead of a pure, basic literal string, perhaps simple casting might solve the problem:

```
linted_data[working_keys[key].toString()] = data[working_keys[key]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Print 1 is logging the keys of an object.  Print 2 is logging a `string[]`. 
 Print 3 is logging **keys** of a `string[]` (0-5).

If you want Print 3 to log the **values** of the string array, use `for (let key of working_keys)`.  The important difference is the **of** instead of **in**.

From the [typescript docs:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html)

> for..of vs. for..in statements Both for..of and for..in statements
>   iterate over lists; the values iterated on are different though,
>   for..in returns a list of keys on the object being iterated, whereas
>   for..of returns a list of values of the numeric properties of the
>   object being iterated.